# Looping with multidimensional arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

So I have an Array set up as follows

```
Array
(
    [0] => App\Model\Entity\Member Object
        (
            [id] => 20
            [fname] => John
            // ...
            [member_attribute] => Cake\ORM\Entity Object
                (
                    [id] => 13
                    [membership_status] => Active
                    [last_payment] => 1541581496
                    // ...
                 )
)
```

I'm using a foreach loop for the first level

```
foreach ($aArray as $Member => $Value)
```

However I can't access the `[member_attributes]` data because it's in its own array.

Any help?

Comment: "because it's in its own array" No, it's an object. So is `Member`.

Answer (score 0):

The items in your array are objects, so use object notation to access them:

```
foreach ($aArray as $Member => $Value) {
    $id = $Value->member_attribute->id;
}
```

There also is no need to use the key => value form of the foreach, you could just access your Members like:

```
foreach ($aArray as $Member) {
    $id = $Member->member_attribute->id;
}
```

That may be a matter of preference, however, I think it is more clear.